# How to draw a contour plot from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, contour

I want to draw a contour plot using table data.
I have  2 variables and response (3 columns).
I dont understand how to build this plot using it. I tried code below. But I had a next mistake: Input z must be 2D, not 1D.

```
feature_x = data.factor1
feature_y = data.factor2
  
# Creating 2-D grid of features
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(feature_x, feature_y)
  
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
  
Z = data.response
  
# plots filled contour plot
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
  
ax.set_title('Filled Contour Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('feature_x')
ax.set_ylabel('feature_y')
  
plt.show()
```

Data
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try `ax.tricontourf(data.factor1, data.factor2, data.response)` when the x and y values aren't arranged on a grid.

Comment: Can you post the results of `data.factor1.shape`, `data.factor2.shape` and `data.response.shape`? If `Z` is not a 2d matrix with values to assign to each 2d point [x,y] you cannot have a contour plot because you have got not enough data. Say, `feature_x` and `feature_y` are 1d arrays of 100 elements, `Z` needs to be a (100,100) matrix

Comment: Also, can you please provide samples for x, y and z?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The shape of x,y,z is (12, )

Comment: I added example of my dataset to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a contour plot, `z` needs to be 2d matrix with all values for the points `(x,y)`. You can think the data needed for a contour plot, as a DataFrame where index is `x`, columns are `y` and values are `z`. So `z` needs to be a 2d array of shape `(x.size, y.size)`.

Since your `z` is not a 2d matrix but a 1d array, you cannot have a contour plot.

What you can do, for example, is a `relplot` with `hue` and/or `size`

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
z = np.array([249, 523, 603, 775, 577, 763, 808, 695, 642, 525, 795, 758])
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})

sns.relplot(
    data=df,
    x='x', y='y',
    size='z', sizes=(10, 100),
    hue='z',
    palette='coolwarm',
);
```

[image]

## EDIT

But... if you're looking for a continuous estimate, you can use `gaussian_kde`, for example

```
import scipy.stats as sps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

offset = .25
xmin = x.min()-offset
xmax = x.max()+offset
ymin = y.min()-offset
ymax = y.max()+offset

X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = sps.gaussian_kde(values, weights=z)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax],
          aspect='auto'
         )
sns.scatterplot(
    data=df,
    x='x', y='y',
    size='z', sizes=(10, 200),
    color='k'
)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: PS: with "continuous" I mean that your data x,y ∈ N² and with gaussian_kde you can have X,Y ∈ A² ⊂ R²

Comment: When the z data are negative, an error, "aweights cannot be negative" comes out.

Comment: You can add a line `z -= z.min() if z.min()<0 else 0`, so that the minimum `z` is 0 if there are negative `z` values